# How to use virtual environnement with VS Code?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, python-venv

I used Sublime Text so far for my Django / Python developments but I want a more complete IDE including debug and console built and my choice was focused on VS COde

the problem is that I have a little trouble to start, or more exactly to launch a project

I developed a project in a virtual environment venv
I can not activate this virtual environment from VS Code Console

I read the VS Code doc about it and you have to select a Python interpreter Ctrl + Shift + P but I do not see my virtual environment

can someone explain to me and help me?
thanks in advance

Comment: The Docs have everything you need. If you can't see your venv, it means it is in a location that the extension does not check for venvs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what implementation of virtual environments you are using.
If you are using the standard `venv` or an implementation that's similar to it, such as `virtualenv`, just create the environment in a subfolder of your project, like this:

[image]

It will be auto-detected in this case. If you are using something like `virtualenvwrapper` or `pipenv`, the environments should be auto-detected as well.

However, if VSCode is failing to find your environment automatically, you may set the path to it manually. Inside your project root, create `.vscode/settings.json` with the following in it:

```
{"python.pythonPath": "path/to/python.exe"}
```